# Reset a const variable to its default value in vue

Tags: vue.js, combobox, constants

How can I reset the value of my constant variable in vue? Here is what I meant:

```
data(){
    const _hdrList = [
        {
           label: 'start_time',
           value: 'start_time'
        },            
        {
           label: 'name',
           value: 'name'
        },
        {
           label: 'another',
           value: 'another'
        },
    ];
    const _cboList = [
        {start_time:''},
        {name:''},
        {another:''},
    ];
    return{
        hdrList:_hdrList,
        headercbo:_cboList,
        columns:[],
    }
}
```

After that, I access it using the following:

```
<tr>
   <th v-for="(col, index) in columns" :key="index.id">   
       <ui-select
           :options="hdrList"
           v-model="headercbo[index][hdrList[index]['label']]"
       ></ui-select>
    </th>
</tr>
```

The output of this one is like this:

[image]

And when I click the clear button, this combo lists are not reverting back to default which it displays an empty or no selected value. Here's how I do it.

```
clearFields(){
    this.columns = [];
    this.headercbo = [];
}
```

But this one does not clear the fields, they still have the previous selected value with them. How can I totally clear them up and set backs to default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the constant out of data.
2. During reset, you've reassign the default headercbo value with the constant value.

```js
const _hdrList = [
            {
               label: 'start_time',
               value: 'start_time'
            },            
            {
               label: 'name',
               value: 'name'
            },
            {
               label: 'another',
               value: 'another'
            },
        ];
        const _cboList = [
            {start_time:''},
            {name:''},
            {another:''},
        ];
    
    export default {
    data(){
        return{
            hdrList:_hdrList,
            headercbo:_cboList,
            columns:[],
        }
    },
    clearFields() {
      this.columns = [];
      this.headercbo = _cboList;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But with this one, it will return `ReferenceError: _cboList is not defined` error.

Comment: I've moved _cboList out of data function, it won't through error.

Comment: I've tried it out, but it's not clearing the fields :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to make this kind of code :S All I just want is to empty the field when the reset button is clicked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Put what you have in your `data` function into a method named `initialData`, then use that function in your `data` function and in your `clearFields` method.

```
  data() {
    return this.initialData();
  },
  methods: {
    initialData() {
      const _hdrList = [{
          label: 'start_time',
          value: 'start_time'
        },
        {
          label: 'name',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          label: 'another',
          value: 'another'
        },
      ];
      const _cboList = [{
          start_time: ''
        },
        {
          name: ''
        },
        {
          another: ''
        },
      ];
      return {
        hdrList: _hdrList,
        headercbo: _cboList,
        columns: [1,2],
      }
    },
    clearFields() {
      this.columns = [];
      this.headercbo = this.initialData().headercbo;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried it but returns `ReferenceError: _cboList is not defined`. also in my data, I have other data returned like :
`data(){
    return {
         otherData:'',
         otherData1:'',
         otherData2:'',
    }
}`